# ExtJs 4.1 cross browser issue(combo box in header not working)

Tags: cross-browser, extjs4.1

Following code create grid column with combo box in header but only working in IE for other browser combo box is not click able.

```
columns : [ {
       header : 'Selected Year<br/><select  style="width:80px" id="mndyearlist"</select>',menuDisabled : true,width:100}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on header has handler attached, and each click is bubbling up from select. Additionaly there is also drag&drop attached by default, which doesn't help either. So, you should change that behaviour. You can for example extend `Column` like so:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.column.SelectColumn', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    alias: 'widget.selectcolumn',

     // disable D&D
    draggable: false,

    // handle click event
    onElClick: function(e, t) {
        var target = e.getTarget('select');
        // if event is from select supress default behaviour
        if (!target) {
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

Then just use that column in your grid, and your `select` should work.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9aTUY/4/